# Find String in Char iterator

Tags: scala

I have a use case where I need to return a String up to a delimiter String (if found) from an iterator of Char.

The contract:

- if iterator is exhausted (only at the begin), return None
- if the delimiter String is found, return all characters before it (empty String is fine), delimiter will be dropped
- else return the remaining characters
- **do not eagerly exhaust the iterator!**

I do have this working solution, but it feels like Java (which is where I'm coming from)

```
class MyClass(str: String) {
  def nextString(iterator: Iterator[Char]): Option[String] = {
    val sb = new StringBuilder
    if(!iterator.hasNext) return None
    while (iterator.hasNext) {
      sb.append(iterator.next())
      if (sb.endsWith(str)) return Some(sb.stripSuffix(str))
    }
    Some(sb.toString())
  }
}
```

Is there a way I can do this in a more functional way (ideally without changing the method signature)?

Update: Here is how I test this

```
val desmurfer = new MyClass("_smurf_")
val iterator: Iterator[Char] = "Scala_smurf_is_smurf_great_smurf__smurf_".iterator
println(desmurfer.nextString(iterator))
println(desmurfer.nextString(iterator))
println(desmurfer.nextString(iterator))
println(desmurfer.nextString(iterator))
println(desmurfer.nextString(iterator))
println
println(desmurfer.nextString("FooBarBaz".iterator))
println(desmurfer.nextString("".iterator))
```

Output:

```
Some(Scala)
Some(is)
Some(great)
Some()
None

Some(FooBarBaz)
None
```

Comment: what is the sample output you are expecting ?

Comment: @S.Karthik added sample output

Comment: please check the answer

Comment: please check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague provided the makings of this answer, which is a mixture between his original approach and some polishing from my side. Thanks, Evans!
Then another colleague also added some input. Thanks Ako :-)

```
class MyClass(str: String) {
  def nextString(iterator: Iterator[Char]): Option[String] = {

    def nextString(iterator: Iterator[Char], sb: StringBuilder): Option[String] = {
      if (!iterator.hasNext || sb.endsWith(str)) {
        Some(sb.stripSuffix(str))
      } else {
        nextString(iterator, sb.append(iterator.next()))
      }
    }

    if (!iterator.hasNext) None
    else nextString(iterator, new StringBuilder)
  }
}
```

So far, I like this approach best, so I will accept it in two days unless there is a better answer by then.

Comment: You should turn this into an iterator itself. `class MyIterator(iterator:Iterator[Char]) extends Iterator { def hasNext() = iterator.hasNext; def next() = {<body of your nextString, mostly>)}`

Answer (score 3):

How about this one:

```
scala> def nextString(itr: Iterator[Char], sep: String): Option[String] = {
     |    def next(res: String): String =
     |      if(res endsWith sep) res dropRight sep.size else if(itr.hasNext) next(res:+itr.next) else res
     |   if(itr.hasNext) Some(next("")) else None
     | }
nextString: (itr: Iterator[Char], sep: String)Option[String]

scala> val iterator: Iterator[Char] = "Scala_smurf_is_smurf_great".iterator
iterator: Iterator[Char] = non-empty iterator

scala> println(nextString(iterator, "_smurf_"))
Some(Scala)

scala> println(nextString(iterator, "_smurf_"))
Some(is)

scala> println(nextString(iterator, "_smurf_"))
Some(great)

scala> println(nextString(iterator, "_smurf_"))
None

scala> println(nextString("FooBarBaz".iterator, "_smurf_"))
Some(FooBarBaz)
```

Comment: This is nice, but I guess `:+` should be O(n) and also have memory issues with lots of calls. Please see my answer (much-much bigger though) as my try on an improvement. Your answer still might be better because of simplicity

Answer (score 3):

What about this one?

```
def nextString(iterator: Iterator[Char]): Option[String] = {
    val t = iterator.toStream

    val index = t.indexOfSlice(s)
    if(t.isEmpty) None
    else if(index == -1) Some(t.mkString)
    else Some(t.slice(0,index).mkString)
  }
```

it passed this tests:

```
val desmurfer = new MyClass("_smurf_")
val iterator: Iterator[Char] = "Scala_smurf_is_smurf_great_smurf__smurf_".iterator
assert(desmurfer.nextString(iterator) == Some("Scala"))
assert(desmurfer.nextString(iterator) == Some("is"))
assert(desmurfer.nextString(iterator) == Some("great"))
assert(desmurfer.nextString(iterator) == Some(""))
assert(desmurfer.nextString(iterator) == None)

assert(desmurfer.nextString("FooBarBaz".iterator) == Some("FooBarBaz"))
assert(desmurfer.nextString("".iterator) == None)
```

**Updated**: removed "index == -1 &&" from the first "if condition clause".

Comment: Very nice indeed.  Just curious: why test `index` twice?  Is it possible for `t.isEmpty` while at the same time `index != -1`?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be doing what you'd want. @Eastsun answer motivated me

```
val str = "hello"

  def nextString2(iterator: Iterator[Char]): Option[String] = {
    val maxSize = str.size
    @tailrec
    def inner(collected: List[Char], queue: Queue[Char]): Option[List[Char]] =
      if (queue.size == maxSize && queue.sameElements(str))
        Some(collected.reverse.dropRight(maxSize))
      else
        iterator.find(x => true) match {
          case Some(el) => inner(el :: collected, if (queue.size == maxSize) queue.dequeue._2.enqueue(el) else queue.enqueue(el))
          case None => Some(collected.reverse)
        }

    if (iterator.hasNext)
      inner(Nil, Queue.empty).map(_.mkString)
    else
      None
  }

  test(nextString2(Nil.iterator)) === None
  test(nextString2("".iterator)) === None
  test(nextString2("asd".iterator)) === Some("asd")
  test(nextString2("asfhello".iterator)) === Some("asf")
  test(nextString2("asehelloasdasd".iterator)) === Some("ase")
```

But I honestly think it's too complicated to be used. Sometimes you have to use non FP stuff in scala to be performance effecient.

P.S. I didn't know how to match iterator on it's first element, so I've used `iterator.find(x => true)` which is ugly. Sorry.

P.P.S. A bit of explanation. I recoursively build up `collected` to fill the elements you are searching for. And I also build `queue` with last `str.size`-elements. Then I just check this queue over `str` each time. This might not be the most efficient way of doing this stuff. You might go with Aho–Corasick algorithm or an analogue if you want more.

P.P.P.S. And I am using `iterator` as a state, which is probably not FP way

P.P.P.P.S. And you test passes as well:

```
  val desmurfer = new MyClass("_smurf_")
  val iterator: Iterator[Char] = "Scala_smurf_is_smurf_great".iterator
  test(desmurfer.nextString2(iterator)) === Some("Scala")
  test(desmurfer.nextString2(iterator)) === Some("is")
  test(desmurfer.nextString2(iterator)) === Some("great")
  test(desmurfer.nextString2(iterator)) === None
  println()
  test(desmurfer.nextString2("FooBarBaz".iterator)) === Some("FooBarBaz")
  test(desmurfer.nextString2("".iterator)) === None
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one I'm posting just because it's a bit warped :) I wouldn't recommend actually using it:

```
  class MyClass2(str: String) {
    val sepLength = str.length
    def nextString(iterator: Iterator[Char]): Option[String] = {
      if (!iterator.hasNext) return None

      val sit = iterator.sliding(sepLength)
      val prefix = sit.takeWhile(_.mkString != str).toList

      val prefixString = prefix.toList.map(_.head).mkString
      if (prefix.head.length < sepLength) Some(prefix.head.mkString)
      else if (!iterator.hasNext) Some(prefix.head.mkString + prefix.last.mkString)
      else Some(prefixString)

    }
  }
```

The idea is that by calling `sliding()` on our underlying iterator, we can get a sequence, one of which will be our delimiter, if it's present. So we can use `takeWhile` to find the delimiter. Then the first characters of each of the sliding strings before our delimiter is the string we skipped over. As I said, warped.

I'd really like `sliding` to be defined so that it produced all subsequences of  length `n` and at the end sequences of length `n-1`, `n-2`....`1` for this particular use case, but it doesn't, and the horrible if statement at the end is dealing with the various cases.

It passes the test cases :)

Comment: I like this one best so far. Had also looked at .sliding but then rejected it as too complicated.

Comment: There are edge cases where the delimiter is the very last thing  or very first thing in the underlying iterator. It messes up in those cases. I may get around to fixing that later.  You probably need more test cases...

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:** This works without converting the iterator to String

```
def nextString(iterator: Iterator[Char]): Option[String] = {
  if (iterator.isEmpty) None
  else Some(iterator.foldLeft("") { (result, currentChar) => if (res.endsWith(str)) result else result + currentChar})
}
```

Comment: If I was allowed to convert to String, the answer would be obvious. The constraint I have is that I should only take as many characters as needed (added that to the contract)

Comment: I missed that part. I have updated my answer to do it without converting the iterator to String

Comment: `foldLeft` still consumes the whole iterator though.

Comment: Yup, The best solution obviously is to use a recursive function. The answer from Eastsun seems to be perfect.